# ingresar registros aleatorios en columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

primero que todo muchas gracias por la disposición. Les cuento mi dilema, dentro de una tabla agregue el campo responsable, para insertar nombres de responsables a quienes se les asignará X tarea. Estos nombres corresponden a integrantes de mi equipo de trabajo. Y necesito buscar una función que asigne de manera aleatoria un nombre por cada tarea. Lamentablemente no he encontrado algo que me pueda ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Esto va a requerir un poco de trabajo por tu lado. Una alternativa sería suponer que tienes el listado de responsables en alguna tabla (en mi código, voy a crear esa tabla como una CTE):

```
WITH Responsables AS -- Esta es la tabla de Responsables
(
    SELECT 1 Id, 'JOB' Nombre
    UNION
    SELECT 2, 'EVELYN'
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 'DAVID'
), Tareas AS
(
    SELECT 
         *, 
         ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 3 + 1 IdResponsable --Acá el "3" es el número de responsables a distribuir
    FROM dbo.Tareas
)
SELECT t.*, r.Nombre Responsable
FROM Tareas t
LEFT JOIN Responsables r
    ON r.Id = t.IdResponsable
;
```

Con esto puedes ver que se distribuye un responsable para cada tarea en forma aleatoria. Por tu lado, tendrías que actualizar este valor en la tabla, porque cada vez que ejecutes el `SELECT` el resultado va a ser distinto.